# cgi number guessing game -- storing value in a readable and writeable file

Tags: perl, cgi

I am working on a cgi script for a number guessing game and I want to store the target value in a readable and writeable file. I don't know how to do that, but I believe I can use a system() call to do it and some type of expression to extract the value from that file. I need help determining that solution; I have the following already:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI qw(:standard);
print header, start_html("Guessing Game"), h2("Guessing game"), "\n";

//need some type of system call to store value if one does not exist 
//or read it if it does (random value generated below)

srand( time() ^ ($$ + ($$ << 15)) );
my $target = int(rand 100) + 1; 

if ( !param() ) {
    print hr, "\n", start_form;
    print p("Try to guess a number between 1 and 100: ", textfield("guess")), "\n";
    print end_form, "\n", hr;
} else {
    print hr, "\n", start_form;
    my $guess = param("guess");
    if ($guess > $target) {
        print p ("$guess is too high; try again: ", textfield("guess")), "\n";
    } elsif ($guess < $target) {
        print p ("$guess is too low; try again: ", textfield("guess")), "\n";
    } else {
        print p ("You got it: $guess!");
        //erase value from file
    }
print end_form, "\n", hr;
}
print end_html, "\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) to open a file.

```
use strict;

# Get number
open(my $infh, '<', '/path/to/file') or die "Cannot open: $!";
my $number = <$infh>;
close($infh);
chomp($number); # removes newline, just in case

# Save number
open(my $outfh, '>', '/path/to/file') or die "Cannot open: $!";
print $outfh $number;
close($outfh);
```

Comment: VERY helpful! How can I empty the contents of the file?

Comment: The '>' in opens the file and truncates (clears) if it already exists, so if you open and close it again without printing anything to it, it will be empty. (Opening with '>>' instead, appends to the end of the file what was already there.) If it's already opened, you can use `truncate`. To delete the file, use `unlink`. (See http://perldoc.perl.org to learn how they work.)

Answer (score 3):

While it's certainly possible to store a value in a flat text file, you do need to keep in mind the concurrency issues that a web type environment face.  The first issue is that you will need a session ID for each user, which is often passed back and forth in a hidden field, or in a cookie.  That session ID will need to be stored alongside the target number in this flat file, so that you can identify which magic number corresponds to which session.  And after a period of inactivity, you would need to remove the number.  That's a lot of work, and doesn't even begin to address the problem of several hits coming in at the same time.  You'll have to deal with file locking, etc.

A much saner approach would be to simply pass the magic number back and forth as a hidden field or in a cookie.  A hidden field would be a lot easier though.  And then use a module such as [Crypt::Rijndael](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Crypt%3a%3aRijndael) to encrypt the magic number before passing it, and to decrypt it when receiving it.  ...if that seems like a whole lot more security than you really need, you could just come up with your own strategy such as a base64 encoding, or something like that; lighter-weight, but good enough for a casual viewer.

This avoids the need to keep track of user sessions; each user owns his own session in the form of a hidden field embedded in the guess form.

**UPDATE:** [CGI::Session](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI%3a%3aSession) defaults to storing session information in flat files if a driver isn't specified.  This abstracts away the details of concurrency and session management.

Comment: +1 I appreciate the insight, but this is a theoretical problem I am trying to solve and is only for one user.